# Is it standard compliant to write font-size: 62.5%/1.2em in CSS?

Tags: css

I noticed that some stylesheets have something like this:

```
body { font-size: 62.5%/1.2em; }
```

I got a warning "unexpected token /" when I wrote this in NetBeans. And if I changed the EM value, say,

```
body { font-size: 62.5%/1em; }
```

the computed font-size remained 16px.

My question is, Is it standard compliant to write something like that? And how to computed the actual font-size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In CSS2, the [`font-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-size) does not allow a value of the form `x/y`.

What you're using is the [`font` short hand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font), which allows `x/y` as a short-hand of `font-size: x; line-height: y;`. So either use

```
body { font: 62.5%/1.2em sans-serif; }
/*                       ^^^^^^^^^^ the font-family is needed. */
```

or

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: But why not body { font: 62.5% 1.2em sans-serif; } instead of body { font: 62.5%/1.2em sans-serif; }? And seems that in body, 100% = 1em = 16px, right? Because by writing font-size: 62.5% I got computed font-size is 10px. Thx alot!

Comment: @powerboy: Yes. And whether `1em == 16px` depends on the browser.

Comment: @powerboy: *why not body { font: 62.5% 1.2em sans-serif; }* — Historical issue. "The syntax of this property is based on a traditional typographical shorthand notation to set multiple properties related to fonts."